# Type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Tags: c#, linq

I´m learning LINQ and trying to use Cross join  I get this error: Type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Isn´t possible to use GetCategories() in Cross Join?  This request is in main but the functions outside of it.

```
var q = from c in GetCategories()
        join p in GetProducts() on c equals p.CategoryID
        where c.Name = "Beverages"
        select new { ID = c, p.Name };
```

Method signatures:

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>( );
categories.Add( new Category { ID = 1, Name = "Beverages" } );

public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
List<Product> products = new List<Product>( );
products.Add( new Product { Name = "Milk",           Price = 90,  CategoryID = 4, ID = 1 } );
```

Comment: what are the return types on your methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which field in the `Category` class to join on.. most likely `ID`:

```
from c in GetCategories()
join p in GetProducts() on c.ID equals p.CategoryID
where c.Name == "Beverages"
select new { ID = c.ID, p.Name };
```

Comment: Does this help? 

public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts( )
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories( )

Comment: I did add more lines so you can see how the lists are

Comment: Get 1 Error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

where c.Name = "Beverages"

Can´t figure out how bool comes into it, isn´t possible to find name in LINQ like this?

Comment: Thank you for the help, maybe one last help, I´m trying to print out only the words that starts with G
I did add the line orderby (p.name.Startswith("G")) but it prints every line with the same CategoryID as Beverages, not only words that starts with G.

Comment: Found it out, used orderby but changed it out for where than I got it :)